# Getting a certain element out of the website table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to get only one value from a table on a website. I've been following a tutorial but I am currently stuck. My goal is to extract the name of the country from the table and the number of total cases of that specific country and print it on the screen. For example:

> China: 80,761 Total cases

I'm using Python 3.7.
This is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.findAll('table',{'id':'main_table_countries'})
```

Comment: Now that you've fond the `table`, you can call `.findAll` on that to get the rows and go from there to get the data.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that, even if i find the rows i don't know how to extract a particular row out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `<table>` tags, just go with pandas' `.read_html()`. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood, then you can just slice and dice the dataframe as you please:

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

print (df.iloc[:,:2])
```

To do it with beautifulsoup straight forward. First you want to grab the `<table>` tag. Within the `<table>` tag get all the `<tr>` tages (rows). Then iterate through each row to get all the `<td>` tags (the data). The data you want are in index positions 0 and 1, so just print those out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'main_table_countries'})

rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    if data != []:
        print (data[0].text, data[1].text)
```

**ADDITIONAL:**

```
import pandas as pd

country = 'China'

url='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

print (df[df['Country,Other'] == country].iloc[:,:2])
```

OR

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


country = 'China'

url='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'main_table_countries'})

rows = table.find('a', text=re.compile(country))
for row in rows:
    data = row.parent.parent.parent.find_all('td')[1].text
    print (row, data)
```

Comment: that seems to work, but what if i want to extract only a specific country, not all of them, for example China?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the target info this way:

```
for t in table[0].find_all('tr'):
    target = t.find_all('td')
    if len(target)>0:
        print(target[0].text, target[1].text)
```

Output:

```
China  80,761
 Italy  9,172
 Iran  8,042
```

etc.